# How do we mimic a ActiveRecord callback for update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

How do we mimic a ActiveRecord callback for update_all, is there a way to achieve this? The docs say its not possible.

Comment: the doc is correct you cant run callback in `update_all` which make think if you need callback why are you doing `update_all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some info about why do you need callbacks when doing 'update_all' would be helpful.
Maybe you could use database triggers for that. Or, if you want to reuse some existing ruby code and it is not crucial to have immediate effect you could process updated records with some background ruby process.